# angular 2 bind to component selector

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a component that I needs to be hidden when a property is true. Is there a way to solve this within the component itself.

Example:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'prio-tab',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  template:
  `
      <div [hidden]="!active">
        stuff
      </div>
    `
})

export class PrioTabComponent {
  @Input() title;
  active:boolean = false;
}
```

Here I would like to have the actual "prio-tab" element to depend on active-flag. Not just the content inside prio-tab.

Or is it maybe possible to use itself when declaring the prio-tab  tag, like this:

```
<prio-tab [hidden]="this.active">
     stuff
</prio-tab>
```

I guess a working solution would be to create a reference to the prio-tab component in its parent and then go through the parent. But how would I do if I have multiple prio-tab's ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `@HostBinding()`

```
export class PrioTabComponent {
  @Input() title;

  @HostBinding('hidden')
  active:boolean = false;
}
```

Comment: That is bloody marvelous !